# Adding multiple attributes to a device in a Linux PCI driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am currently writing my first linux driver trying to communicate witha PCI card. With the help of [Linux Device Driver, 3rd edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) and this [great example](http://haifux.org/lectures/256/haifux-pcie.pdf) I was able to code my first modules and to understand and to implement the basics (device detection, memory mapping, DMA, MSI). In a next step I would like to establish a connection between the PCI card's memory and the user space via sysfs and the help of device attributes. Unfortunately currently my module does not go further than produce an oops, this is why I would like to ask you.

In order to add multiple attributes to the device I create them as following:

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(foo, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_foo, set_foo);
static DEVICE_ATTR(bar, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_bar, set_bar);

static struct device_attribute *pci_device_attrs[] = {
    __ATTR(foo, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_foo, set_foo),
    __ATTR(bar, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_bar, set_bar),
    __ATTR_NULL,
};
static struct attribute_group pci_device_attr_group = {
    .attrs = pci_device_attrs,
};
```

But in contrast to `struct device` the device class of PCI devices (`struct pci_dev`) does not contain a `struct attribute_group` attribute. So how can I add my `attribute_group` variable to my `pci_dev` variable? I have tried so far the following in my `probe()` function, both fail in compilation due to the missing element `group` in `pci_dev`.

```
pci_device->groups = pci_device_attr_group;
pci_device->dev->groups = pci_device_attr_group;
```

[GregKH explains on his blog](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) one should simply add an additional field to the `pci_dev` structure which I do not know how to implement.

Any help and/or examples are much appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

actually after having a closer look at [Documentation/driver-model/device.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/device.txt) I modified my code example slightly to the following

```
static DEVICE_ATTR(foo, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_foo, set_foo);
static DEVICE_ATTR(bar, S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO, show_bar, set_bar);

static struct device_attribute *pci_device_attrs[] = {
    &dev_attr_foo.attr,
    &dev_attr_bar.attr,
    NULL,
};
static struct attribute_group pci_device_attr_group = {
    .attrs = pci_device_attrs,
};
static const struct attribute_group *pci_device_attr_groups[] = {
    &pci_device_attr_group,
    NULL,
};
```

Comment: Referring to adding `groups` to the structure, what you want to do is create a new structure that includes a `pci_dev` member and a `struct attribute_group **` member: `struct my_pci_dev { struct pci_dev inner_dev; const struct attribute_group **groups; };`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I am not sure if this is a question or an answer but I actually do not want to create a new structure: As Greg pointed out in his blog I should add the attr_group to the struct pci_dev which I am obviously not able to. Now I am searching for an alternative or an explanation of Gregs indication

Comment: This is pretty much the easiest way to do it - you can't really add a field to a kernel-provided structure.

Comment: I guess so ;) but how is then the device (and so sysfs) aware of the attributes? - which is my actual goal.

Comment: Good point - in that case, I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"struct pci_driver" contains a "struct device_driver" (option 1).
"struct pci_dev" contains a "struct device" (option 2)

Look at the structure definitions in include/linux/pci.h

The advice from GregKH is not to add a field to the structure, but to fill in the existing field.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I tried with `pci_device->dev->groups = pci_device_attr_group;` as mentioned in my question. I get an error in compilation: "invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct device')"

Comment: I think that should be `pci_device->dev.groups = pci_device_attr_group;`  (note '.' in place of the second '->') The pci_dev does not *point* to the 'struct device', it actually contains it.

Comment: True! Thanks a lot! Actually I did another error in my code which I will correct in the question itself.